# Subgroups of Compact groups are exactly the totally bounded groups.

Tags: compactness, topological-groups

If $G$ is a compact topological group, then how can we prove that subgroups of $G$ are exactly the totally bounded groups.

$\textbf{Note}$: We call a topological group $G$, totally bounded or precompact if $G$ can be covered by finitely many translates of any neighbourhood of identity.

Comment: Are you asking whether all subgroups of a compact group are totally bounded?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos As I interpret the question, he wants to show that all of the subgroups of all compact groups are totally bounded, *and* that every totally bounded group is a subgroup of some compact group. Basically, a group is totally bounded if and only if it is a subgroup of a compact group.

Comment: @TheoBendit That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: If Theo Bendit's interpretation is correct: Every subspace of a totally bounded space is totally bounded, so subgroups of compact groups are totally bounded. The completion of a totally bounded space is compact, and since the completion of a topological group is a topological group, the completion of a totally bounded group is a compact group.

Comment: @DanielFischer as the notion of totally boundedness differs here, compact groups need not be totally bounded groups.

Comment: A compact group is totally bounded, in the sense of the question as well as in the sense of uniform spaces. For abelian groups, the notion of total boundedness used in the question coincides with total boundedness as uniform spaces, and completion gives a compact group. However, for non-abelian groups things are different. If you require all translates to be left translates, or all right, you get [left/right totally bounded groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#Definitions_in_other_contexts), and these notions are often weaker than the uniform space notion.

Comment: And then the completion argument doesn't work, I think. The direction "a subgroup of a compact group is totally bounded" holds. The other direction may be wrong. A subgroup of a compact group is totally bounded in the uniform space sense, and that implies it is both, left-totally bounded and right-totally bounded in the above sense.